# jQuery - Unable to select value of an element added using elementor

Tags: javascript, jquery, elementor

I have this code in elementor custom code

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#ship-price').on('click', function(){
            var originalPrice = $('#product-price').val();
            console.log(originalPrice);
            //
            var shipPrice = $('#ship-price').val();          
            console.log(shipPrice);
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to select two elements that I've added using elementor and where I have assigned a css id. It will occur that I'm unable to read the product price and ship price values.

What I need to achive is to show a different product price that is loaded using woocommerce,  after the user click. How I can fix the problem?

**UPDATE**
this is the html of the product price

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2cf415f elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="2cf415f" data-element_type="widget" id="product-price" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>499,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span>*</h2>        </div>
                </div>
```

And this is the rendered html for the ship price I need to get

```html
<div id="elementor-tab-content-3201" class="elementor-tab-content elementor-clearfix elementor-active" data-tab="1" role="region" aria-labelledby="elementor-tab-title-3201" style="display: block;"><ul>
<li><a href="#" id="ship-price-a">70€ + IVA</a> ...</li>
<li><a href="#" id="ship-price-b">79€ + IVA</a> ...</li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Kindly add the rendered html of those input fields and buttons in your question. (rendered HTML on your browser)

Comment: They are not buttons or input fields, the two elements I've used are anchor tag and the product price is nested inside some div

Comment: Until we can see html, how can we know what's going wrong? You have to share HTML

Comment: It's possible that the element you're trying to select is added to the DOM after your code is already added in. In which case, this won't work. I believe that is likely to be the issue. But as @Death-is-the-real-truth said, kindly share your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Since your Id's are not straightforward so use `*` to match them

b) Also, none of your prices is inside the input element, they are inside some HTML elements so use `.text()` rather than `.val()`

c) Product price is coming under the child element of the `#product-price` element so you have to modify that code too.

Working snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[id*=ship-price]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var originalPrice = $('#product-price').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    console.log(originalPrice);

    var shipPrice = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    console.log(shipPrice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-2cf415f elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="2cf415f" data-element_type="widget" id="product-price" data-widget_type="heading.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>499,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi>
      </span>*</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="elementor-tab-content-3201" class="elementor-tab-content elementor-clearfix elementor-active" data-tab="1" role="region" aria-labelledby="elementor-tab-title-3201" style="display: block;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="ship-price-a">70€ + IVA</a> ...</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="ship-price-b">79€ + IVA</a> ...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thenk you. Just a question, it's supposed that `.val()` can set the displayed text of an html element set using jQuery?

Comment: `.val()` used to set/get value of input elements